# Key versioning for memcached

Tags: php, memcached

I'm looking for a PHP class which would implement delete($prefix) through the means of key versioning for memcached (or other cache).

If I have a key structure like this:

```
table/5/23 => {data}
table/5/24 => {data}
table/6/5 => {data}
```

When I want to invalidate part of the cache, such as clear everything for table/ or table/5 the only option seems to be is to use key versioning as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202174/memcache-invalidate-entries-according-to-a-pattern/1217198#1217198).

Is there an existing PHP class, library or snippet which implements such functionality transparently?

(note: I've looked into MongoDB but I can't use it in my project)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex on memcached key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497159/regex-on-memcached-key)

Comment: yeah, thanks for pointing this out. added my vote for closing this.

Comment: Yup, I'm sorry therer isn't a better answer, but the fact memcached can't do it is one of the reasons it's fast.

Comment: I have already implemented versioned keys. Works like a charm. I made function to split path into "table" "5" "23" and look up their versions in versions/table, versions/table/5, versions/table/5/23. Each contains a number. When I need to delete table/5 I increment versions/table/5. Actual data key after deletion will look like this: 1:table/2:5/1:23. It's quite fast, one extra multi-get.